# Set Expanded as default in rChart stackedAreaChart with NVD3

Tags: r, rcharts, nvd3.js, slidify

When creating a `stackedAreaChart` with `rChart` and `nvd3`, the default setting is Stacked. Is there a way to set Expanded as default? Here is the code:

```
dat <- data.frame(t=rep(0:23,each=4),var=rep(LETTERS[1:4],4),val=round(runif(4*24,0,50)))
p8 <- nPlot(val ~ t, group =  'var', data = dat, type = 'stackedAreaChart', id = 'chart')
p8
```

Doing `p8$chart(stacked = TRUE)` works for `multiBarChart`, but `p8$chart(expanded = TRUE)` does not work with `stackedAreaChart`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
p8$chart(style = 'expand')
```

Comment: It is generally considered helpful to explain why an answer solves a problem rather than just providing code, this way future visitors to the site who may not have the exact same question but a similar problem can also benefit from your answer

Comment: At the end of `nvd3` chart models, such as in this case `stackedArea` you will see a section with `getters` and `setters` [github source for stackedArea][1].  These generally give clues to what options are available.  [These lines][2] tell us there is a `style` option with potential values as `stack`, `stream`, `stream-center`, `expand`, and `stack_percent`.


  [1]: https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/stackedArea.js#L257-L368
  [2]: https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/stackedArea.js#L329-L357